# How to retrieve deeply nested data form SWIFT dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am struggling to achieve the following and need your kind help in dealing with dictionaries in swift:

1. How to get "Nobody" "Image" value? it should be "Nobody.png"
2. How to the count of BestMoments members? (it should be 3 for first movie and 4 for second movie"
3. how to get values inside Bestmoments for "Nobody" (like :"Survive", 120, 8)?

```
 var MV = [
        ["Nobody": [
            ["YEAR" : "2021"] ,
            ["IMAGE" : "Nobody.png"] ,
            ["GENRE" : "Action/Thriller"] ,
            ["DURATIONhours" : 1] ,
            ["DURATIONmintues" : 36] ,
            ["DURATIONseconds" : 17] ,
            ["BestMoments" : [["Win", 25, 5], ["Survive", 120, 8], ["Lose", 240, 15]]]
        ]],
        ["Godzilla vs. Kong": [
            ["YEAR" : "2021"] ,
            ["IMAGE" : "Nobody.png"] ,
            ["GENRE" : "Action/Sci-fi"] ,
            ["DURATIONhours" : 1] ,
            ["DURATIONmintues" : 22] ,
            ["DURATIONseconds" : 45] ,
            ["BestMoments" : [["Win", 34, 6], ["Survive", 120, 8], ["Twist", 233, 3], ["Lose", 340, 12]]]
        ]],
    ]
```

I tried the following to access the data (with outcome):

`print(MV[0])` 
// prints all data for the first movie

`print(MV["Nobody"])`
// No exact matches in call to subscript

`print([MV[0].keys])` 
// prints the name of the first movie which is the key

```
for (movie, data) in MV2 {
        print(data)
        }
```

//Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type [String : [[String : Any]]]

Comment: What have you tried, what exactly is the problem with accessing the dictionary?

Comment: After looking at this some more I can understand this isn't easy. What is the source of this structure because it looks really bad, maybe the solution here is to simplify the data instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you, i added some attempts (edited question) after which I couldn't get further. Do you mean its not doable with this data structure?

Comment: It's always doable :) What I mean it could be much easier with a better structure.

Comment: Before using this data model, convert it to something usable. Start by defining a good `struct` hierarchy, then think how to map your data to that hierarchy. Hint - in the resulting hierarchy there should be only one (or no) dictionary.

Comment: @Sulthan I tried, but could manage having the "Best Moments" array in it: PART 1                                                                                                                      struct MASSstruct {
var title: String
var year: Int
var image: String
var genre: String
var DURATIONhours: Int
var DURATIONmintues: Int
var DURATIONseconds: Int

Comment: @Sulthan PART 2: init(title: String, year: Int, image: String, genre: String , DURATIONhours: Int, DURATIONmintues: Int, DURATIONseconds: Int) {
self.title = title
self.year = year
self.image = image
self.genre = genre
self.DURATIONhours = DURATIONhours
self.DURATIONmintues = DURATIONmintues
self.DURATIONseconds = DURATIONseconds
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the data better:

```
struct BestMoment {
    enum MomentType: String {
        case win = "Win"
        case survive = "Survive"
        case lose = "Lose"
        case twist = "Twist"
    }

    let type: MomentType
    let start: Int
    let duration: Int
}

struct Duration {
    let hours: Int
    let minutes: Int
    let seconds: Int
}

struct Movie {
    let name: String
    let year: Int
    let image: String
    let genre: String
    let duration: Duration
    let bestMoments: [BestMoment]
}

let movies = [
    Movie(
        name: "Nobody",
        year: 2021,
        image: "Nobody.png",
        genre: "Action/Thriller",
        duration: Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 36, seconds: 16),
        bestMoments: [
            BestMoment(type: .win, start: 25, duration: 5),
            BestMoment(type: .survive, start: 120, duration: 8),
            BestMoment(type: .lose, start: 240, duration: 15)
        ]
    ),
    Movie(
        name: "Godzilla vs. Kong",
        year: 2021,
        image: "Nobody.png",
        genre: "Action/Sci-fi",
        duration: Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 22, seconds: 45),
        bestMoments: [
            BestMoment(type: .win, start: 34, duration: 6),
            BestMoment(type: .survive, start: 120, duration: 8),
            BestMoment(type: .twist, start: 233, duration: 3),
            BestMoment(type: .lose, start: 340, duration: 12)
        ]
    )
]
```

Then your operations are simple:

1. `movies.first { $0.name == "Nobody" }?.image`
2. `movies.first { $0.name == "Nobody" }?.bestMoments.count`
3. `movies.first { $0.name == "Nobody" }?.bestMoments`

You could probably even wrap your movie library into an additional object that will simplify the search of movies.

Duration should be probably represented only in seconds and converted to hours/minutes/seconds only when needed. `Genre` could be probably an `enum`.

Comment: thank you for your effort. I got this error when i tested: '$' is not an identifier; use backticks to escape it

Comment: @ooenomel2003 My fault, fixed.

Comment: @ooenomel2003 That's problem is on you. I can can give you the code but you have to know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The data in question has a very complex data structure and is difficult to manage. I think it would be better to have a simpler structure.

However, you can access the data you want in the following way.
Try to print the result.

```swift
/// 1. How to get "Nobody" "Image" value? it should be "Nobody.png"
let imageOfNobady = MV[0]["Nobody"]![1]["IMAGE"]

/// 2. How to the count of BestMoments members? (it should be 3 for first movie and 4 for second movie"
let bestmomentsForNobady = MV[0]["Nobody"]![6]["BestMoments"] as! [Any]
let countOfBestmomentsForNobady = bestmomentsForNobady.count

/// 3. how to get values inside Bestmoments for "Nobody" (like :"Survive", 120, 8)?
let survieInfo = bestmomentsForNobady[1]
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. For the 3rd question, I actually wanted to identify one element like "Survive", not all "Survive", 120, 8 together

Comment: @ooenomel2003 "Great answer", I have to disagree with this since this answer uses to many hard coded indices. One small change to the top or sub arrays and it will not work anymore. Actually since so much is hard coded the first one could might as well be shortened to `let imageOfNobady = "Nobody.png"`for instance

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I agree with you. This is not a "Great answer". But it can't be  helped because the original data struct is not good. So, I think it would be better to have a simpler data structure.